# Installed create-react-class plugin and used createReactClass but it is throwing error "createReactClass is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I installed create-react-class plugin and used `createReactClass`. It is throwing this error: `createReactClass is not defined` in my application, but works properly in a React sample application. When I import '@boldreports/react-reporting-components/Scripts/bold.reports.react.min' I am getting the error what I believe.

[image: image for reference]

Comment: import statement like this: `import createReactClass from "create-react-class";`